# What causes dead time in a Geiger Muller tube?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I’ve been trying to work out if this is to do with electron avalanches caused by the ionisation of the gas in the chamber but can’t find much more online than “the detector needs time to reset”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR -- dead time comes from resetting the detector, not doing this will cause a runaway process.**

As a quick recap of the way a Geiger-Muller counter works:

1. Radiation enters the chamber, which is filled with a neutral gas (usually He, or Ar).
2. The radiation ionizes gas particles, knocking out electrons, which become free.
3. A strong electric field applied across the detector accelerates the electrons, which knock into other gas particles and ionize them. (This is known as the *Townshend Avalanche*.)
4. The detector registers the cascade of electrons along the anode as a *pulse*.

If this occurs, note that many of the gas particles in the chamber are ionized. This is known as the *active state*. The ionized particles are attracted to the cathode, and when they grab electrons and become neutral, they might end up in a higher energy state (*isomerism*) which decay to the ground state through photon emission. But, this can cause a runaway process! More emissions will cause more ionization, etc. etc.

To avoid this, the gas is quenched. A common way of doing this is to add a compound (usually Br, Cl) which can absorb the energy and charge from the ionized gas. When these molecules reach the cathode, they decay to a ground state without emitting photons, by forming compounds. However, this process does take some time, as the collisions are stochastic. This is the *dead time* you are asking about.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of what's left over after the avalanche. You have electrons crashing into atoms, freeing more electrons, smashing into the anode, shooting out photons which trigger more cascades, until the whole tube lights up (you can see it in the dark if the coating on your mica window is flaking off). That's in contrast to a proportional counter, which is designed to create one well-defined cascade per ionization event. The GM tube just keeps going until it can't go any more.

The electrons move so quickly, the ions are basically stationary during the whole process, and a space charge builds up, distorting the electric field until an avalanche can no longer be triggered. That's what prevents a continuous discharge. You have to wait until the ions clear and neutralize sufficiently before it can support another avalanche. That's the dominant contribution to the deadtime. The electronics are fast by comparison.

And then there comes a point where a baby avalanche could be triggered if you have another ionization event at just the right time, but it doesn't produce a big enough signal to get past the discriminator, so the ions have to clear all over again, but you didn't get a count that time. So, while GM tubes are usually modeled as non-paralyzable, they are actually semi-paralyzable with a paralysis factor of about 0.05, which is small but still non-zero.

(And some of those ions are slow enough that they could also trigger a new avalanche when they neutralize, unless they're quenched. But that's spurious counts, or multiple counts, not deadtime.)